# Getting 'Posix spawn failure' error - Appium iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, automation, ios-simulator, appium

I am trying to run my automation scripts for one app using Java in Appium iOS.

When I am running on Simulator , getting the following error -

```
info: Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: Attempting to run app on iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1

info: Spawning instruments with command:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -w iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1 /Users/abc/Desktop/smriti/iPhoneSimulator/AppIOS.app -e UIASCRIPT /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/uiauto/bootstrap.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd"}
info: And launch timeout: 90000ms

info: [INST STDERR] posix spawn failure; aborting launch (binary == /Users/abc/Desktop/smriti/iPhoneSimulator/AppIOS.app/AppIOS).

info: [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting Recording
```

Then tried running on real device , then getting following error :

```
info: Installing ipa found at AppIOS.ipa
info: Creating iDevice object with udid 3daa1240e495c84e8878996649301fd9759a07df
info: Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller

info: Cleaning up appium session

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libimobiledevice.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
Reason: image not found


info: Error: Command failed: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libimobiledevice.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
Reason: image not found

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)

info: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libimobiledevice.3.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller\n  Reason: image not found\n)","killed":false,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTRAP","origValue":"Command failed: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libimobiledevice.3.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller\n  Reason: image not found\n"},"sessionId":null}
POST /wd/hub/session 500 4286ms - 714b
```

Then I clicked on 'i' to launch Appium inspector when running on real device -> it launched my app and then app crashed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you resolved it yet???

Comment: Just in case somebody is struggling the same: I resolved this very annoying and frustrating problem by removing platformVersion from my desired capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the advice in either of these two threads?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/frhUdnCHMms

Or this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appium-discuss/HepKHApmm6w/mu6uGLyNLk0J

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt installing IPA files on the simulator.
AFAIK, they were built for ARM processors and can run on the iOS devices only.